# Python NLTK bigram/trigram logic for word count

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm fairly new to NLP but I was wondering if was possible for nltk to detect whether a group of 3 words should have bigram, trigram or neither logic applied?

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a program that gives a phrase/word count on large text files. I can get single word counts, two word phrase counts, and three word phrase counts easy enough using bigram/trigram but I'm looking to combine the 3 so I can create a word cloud that includes single words, two word phrases and three word phrase. The program would have to have some way of intelligently guessing if a group of 3 words should be returned as single word, two words, or 3 words and counted accordingly. Can nltk do something this? Not really sure how I would go about this.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: This is not an easy task. You will find techniques searching for `multiword expressions`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any good python libraries for this or would nltk be able to help?

Comment: I'm not sure about nltk. You will need some [lexicons](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/LexSem/). Gensim is a powerful python library. For your case see [phrases](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html)